# How to full screen chrome tab on a mac

Tags: google-chrome, shortcut, fullscreen

I recently switched to a Mac M1 from Windows, and I'm trying to full-screen a Chrome tab so you can't see the search bar, bookmarks bar, and all the other tabs. On Windows, I'm used to pressing <kbd>F11</kbd> and it does just that. I've tried using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and this doesn't achieve what I want since you can still see the search bar, etc. at the top.

How do I do this on Mac? (Preferably, there's a shortcut for it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works in Brave (I don't have Chrome): while in full-screen mode, on menu bar untick View -> Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen.

Comment: Thanks @Aivar Paalberg this works perfectly in chrome too!

Answer (score 5):

With the Chrome Window in full screen mode (green button, View > Enter Fullscreen, or <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>), the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> (View > "Always show toolbar in full screen mode") will toggle showing the tab/url/bookmarks bar while in full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Type about:flags in the Chrome address bar and hit Enter.

Step 2: Scroll down the list until you see Compact Navigation.

Step 3: Enable Compact Navigation and let Chrome restart to access the feature.

Step 4: Once the Chrome opens, right-click one of the tabs and then select Hide the toolbar.

I hope this helps you :)